# Integrate BuddyPress & Facebook

Tags: plugins, buddypress, facebook

Any idea on what would be the easiest way to integrate BuddyPress with Facebook?

I'm looking for a solution that would enable a BP custom profile that easily gets pre-filled with values from Facebook after the user does a "Connect with Facebook". Some way of mapping FB graph objects to BP profile.

If it's not available I will probably start the work on creating one so if you have any ideas or tips then that would also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: kinda?

To sync wall activities:
http://buddystream.net/

To use Facebook Connect for logging in:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bp-fbconnect/

Comment: That said, I'm quite curious as to what you come up with. It doesn't appear there are any real good ways of doing what you want yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you look at this amazing premium "[BuddyPress Facebook Connect+](http://buddydev.com/buddypress/introducing-buddypress-facebook-connect-advance-facebook-loginregistration-plugin-for-your-buddypress-based-social-network/)" plugin from BuddyDev?

Basic Features:-

- It allows seamless login/registration on BuddyPress site using Facebook as the authentication source
- It works with WordPress Multisite as well as WordPress Standard, with BuddyPress enabled.
- It allows Importing users Facebook data to BuddyPress profile
- Site Administrators Can map Facebook profile fields to BuddyPress profile fields
- Completely localized (not just BuddyPress, but also the Facebook connect sections are localized)
- It uses new Facebook api, so obviously It is very lightweight

Comment: Are you affiliated with this?